# Install IE 9 on older Vista Home Premium PC that needs OS updates

Tags: internet, windows-explorer

I want to install the new IE9 Release Candidate browser on my three-year-old PC with Windows Vista Home Premium 6.0.6001 Service Pack 1 Build 6001. The browser won't install because I need "OS updates," which I assume means Service Pack 2, right? But when I try to install it (either the 32-bit or 64-bit version), it tells me it doesn't apply to my PC, so I'm stuck. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Run windows update and install all of the required updates first then retry installing IE9.

Also I am including the system requirements for IE9.  It sounds like you are okay but just to be sure I am throwing them in.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/help/ie-9/is-the-pre-released-internet-explorer-9-right-for-me

Internet Explorer 9 RC system requirements

Computer/Processor

```
*

  Computer with a 1 gigahertz (GHz) 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor.
```

Operating System

```
*

  Windows Vista 32-bit with Service Pack 2 (SP2) or higher
*

  Windows Vista 64-bit with Service Pack 2 (SP2) or higher

*

  Windows 7 32-bit or higher
*

  Windows 7 64-bit or higher

*

  Windows Server 2008 32-bit with Service Pack 2 (SP2) or higher
*

  Windows Server 2008 64-bit with Service Pack 2 (SP2) or higher

*

  Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit
```

Memory

```
*

  Windows Vista 32-bit – 512 megabytes (MB)
*

  Windows Vista 64-bit – 512 MB

*

  Windows 7 32-bit – 512 MB
*

  Windows 7 64-bit – 512 MB

*

  Windows Server 2008 32-bit – 512 MB
*

  Windows Server 2008 64-bit – 512 MB

*

  Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit – 512 MB
```

Hard Drive Space

```
*

  Windows Vista 32-bit – 70 MB
*

  Windows Vista 64-bit – 120 MB

*

  Windows 7 32-bit – 70 MB
*

  Windows 7 64-bit – 120 MB

*

  Windows Server 2008 32-bit – 150 MB
*

  Windows Server 2008 64-bit – 200 MB

*

  Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit – 200 MB
```

Drive

```
*

  CD-ROM drive (if installation is done from a CD-ROM)
```

Display

```
*

  Super VGA (800 x 600) or higher-resolution monitor with 256 colors
```

Peripherals

```
*

  Modem or Internet connection
*

  Microsoft Mouse, Microsoft IntelliMouse, or compatible pointing device
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running Windows Update an applying all the updates from there.